# Run a function every weekend at midnight?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logic, server-side

so I'm trying to run a function every weekend, Saturday, at 12 am.
I was searching for an answer over here, and I found some people suggesting the use of timeout, but it's not really what I want because I don't think it solves the problem that I'm having

so when the server starts, I should get a date from the database 
let's say it was Friday 22/5/2020 (this should happen every weekend)

I want the server to do some requests/computations at Saturday 23/5/2020 midnight

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
while(true){

if(current_date==next_week){
//do stuff that i want ...

next_week=next_week+ 1 week

}

//update current_date
}
```

is it considered a bad idea to run a while loop on the server in general? or it's an okay idea?
if it a bad idea, is there any better ways to solve this problem?

Comment: "*is it considered a bad idea to run a while loop on the server in general?*" it's an **extremely** bad idea. You'll hog the thread forever and nothing else would be able to work.

Comment: I have never really tried doing this tbh, that's why I'm asking, I know that if you try doing an infinite loop inside the browser, it will cause it to crash, but I'm not sure if it's fine to do so on the server or if its not. I guess they are the same then

Comment: You're basically telling your server "Use 100% of your CPU power, 24 hours a day, to do one thing continuously and nothing else : check several millions of times each second if now is Saturday 12am". There is probably a cleverer approach to do that :) Like cron jobs, or at the very least an interval that checks the condition every hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use on of the node modules for [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) management, [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) is good and nice npm module for such a task, also [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) do the same thing, using `timeout` functions is not the right choice here, long running process should be managed using well written module for that use and utilize the OS system calls and APIs.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, and for clearing the doubt of using a function like timeout. ill definitely take a look into this module. have a nice day/night :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use cron job to setup time for running your function.

Run from your terminal: crontab -e

and then setup the time by this format: * * * * *

```
1st*: minute (0-59), 
2nd*: hour (0-23),
3rd*: day of month (1-31),
4th*: month (1-12),
5th*: day of week (0-6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
```